# Select Distinct has Duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have this query that is clearly producing duplicates, but I don't see why since I have the DISTINCT option in use here.

I just migrated SQL servers from one running SQL version 12.0.6329.1 to 13.0.6419.1 (2014 to 2016 I believe)
and I don't experience the same issue on the old server.

Any ideas why DISTINCT isn't working as [*I*] expected?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 [UWI_vn]
,[WI_PrdWellCnt]
,[AAV_GUID]
,[InResFlag]
FROM [AAV_WellStore].[dbo].[V_ResultsProdBdgtOpsUpLiveBaseV4.5]
WHERE [InResFlag] =1
AND [WI_PrdWellCnt] > 0
AND [UWI_vn] = '102/16-25-069-05W6/0'
```

[image]

Comment: Try hashing each row and see if the value is the same:`binary_checksum( [UWI_vn]
,[WI_PrdWellCnt]
,[AAV_GUID]
,[InResFlag])`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: What data type is `[WI_PrdWellCnt]`? Is it an approximate numeric type like `FLOAT` maybe?

Comment: @dfundako The Checksum does not match. Strange.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The datatype of the underlying table is Float, yes.

Comment: @KickingAustin Checksum each field one at a time to find the different one.

Comment: @dfundako I believe ThorstenKettner hit the nail on the head. The float column has 2 values for the checksum.

Comment: Not sure if this was clear, but an approximate numeric like float will not be unique. Store as a decimal if you are doing any kind of exact comparison. Floats are used for speed and approximations.

Comment: Maybe a group by instead of distinct can help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to dfundako for the checksum trick and ThorstenKettner and KeithL for bringing up the intrinsic properties of the float column.

The [WI_PrdWellCnt] column is a float and goes through a CTE that aggregates hundereds of rows to get down to one row. This average must be whats causing the issue. You'd expect the average to be the same if all values are the same, but they arent We've broken this value out and calculated it separately so we don't have to deal with this issue.

Casting [WI_PrdWellCnt] to Real would also potentially solve the issue. (Casting to Decimal as suggested in this thread loses precision and rounds up to 1 in my example) The tables are produced by a proprietary application so altering the base tables is not an option.